# Chrome devtools mobile dimensions appear smaller than screen displayed?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my page mobile responsive. However, I am not sure why the devtools "screen" looks bigger than the px listed on my elemnt. For example my html is 390x844 but looks significantly smaller than the screen that is displaying(also "390x844). Am I misunderstanding the way devtools displays the screen? Or is my css just messed up.

[image: Pixels Comparison]

Navbar.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/navbar.css";
export default function Navbar() {
  const iconImg = "https://pngimg.com/uploads/pokemon/pokemon_PNG146.png";
  function resetBackground() {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color-background", "#c0ebe6");
  }
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="left">
        <Link className="pikachu" to="/" onClick={resetBackground}>
          <img src={iconImg} className="pikachu-logo" />
        </Link>
        <p className="logo-text">
          <Link className="pokemon-paradise" to="/" onClick={resetBackground}>
            Pokemon Paradise
          </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        <Link to="/" onClick={resetBackground}>
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link to="/pokemon" onClick={resetBackground}>
          Pokemon
        </Link>
        <Link to="/berries" onClick={resetBackground}>
          Berries
        </Link>
        <Link to="/moves" onClick={resetBackground}>
          Moves
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@300&display=swap");
body {
  background-color: #c0ebe6;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
}
.navbar {
  height: 110px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0.2px grey;
}
.pokemon-paradise:hover {
  color: black;
}
.pikachu-logo {
  height: 100px;
}
.logo-text {
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 575;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 550;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.pikachu {
  margin: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 820px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 110px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0.2px grey;
  }
  h1 .hero-text {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Homepage.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/homepage.css";
import CollapsableContent from "./CollapsableContent";
export default function Homepage() {
  return (
    <div className="homepage-container">
      <div className="hero-header">
        <h1 className="hero-text">
          Looking for information on your favorite Pokemon?
        </h1>
        <h2 className="hero-text2">You've come to the right place.</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="button-container">
        <Link to="/pokemon" className="get-started-button">
          Get Started
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

homepage.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@300&display=swap");
.homepage-container {
  background: url("https://freepngimg.com/download/pokemon/37446-1-pokemon-ash-transparent-background.png")
    no-repeat center center;
  background-position-y: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #c0ebe6;
}
a {
  all: unset;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.hero-header {
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.hero-text {
  font-size: 38px;
}
.hero-text2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.get-started-button {
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 500px;
  transition-property: background-color, border-color, color, box-shadow, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  min-width: 160px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 17px 48px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1ed760;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 24%;
}
.get-started-button:hover {
  background-color: #21e065;
}
@media (max-width: 820px) {
  .homepage-container {
    width: 390px;
  }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to post code here directly?

Comment: @Kalnode Just uploaded some of my code. These are the only components on display in the screenshots I posted. I have more code for other components, but it should be irrelevant.

Comment: I suspect its your navbar that isn't responsive. Since you didn't post [mcve] for people to test. I would try some basic testing by lets say renaming your navbar in the HTML so it is intentionally broken, don't change the CSS to match. Then refresh, if the page width is correct, then you can mess with the navbar. If not move down the DOM doing that until it is fixed.

Comment: As a test try putting an `overflow:hidden` on your body in one trial, that should give you some clues as to what @imvain2 mentioned.

Comment: @imvain2 thank you. Yes my navbar was the problem. I will attempt to reprogram the navbar.

Comment: @LearningCoder, I have experienced that same problem many times with various elements. If it ever happens again, look at the elements that are going off the edge of the preview as one or more of those elements are most likely causing the problem.

Comment: After you fix the nav, it doesn't hurt to leave some `overflow:hidden`'s on key containers, to protect against bleed like that.

Comment: @Kalnode Gotcha. I will definite implement that. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my navbar as the comments above mention. Going back through to apply proper styling.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).